# How to retrieve records in a different collection using python's mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a model "Post":

```
class Post(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    body = db.StringField(required=True)
```

Assuming I create a `post` variable with the Post object, but before I save it off I save it to a collection name other than the default (Post) for example:

```
post._meta['collection'] = "customcollection"
post.save();
```

Then how do I fetch all the documents in the **customcollection** with **mongoengine**?

Normally if I did not set **customcollection** I could do something like:

```
for item in Post.objects:
    print item.title
```

But since I set a **customcollection**, I want to be able to do something like:

```
for item in customcollection.objects:
    print item.title
```

Though I get a:

```
NameError: global name 'customcollection' is not defined
```

What do I need to do in syntax to be able to fetch all the Post objects in my **customcollection**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `Post` document class to point to `customcollection` just do this:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    body = db.StringField(required=True)
    meta = {'collection': 'customcollection'}
```

Now when you do:

```
for item in Post.objects:
    print item.title
```

It should read its posts out of the `customcollection` collection.